# Why do PHP logins scripts use GET ID to logout?

Tags: php, authentication

I'm currently building my own login script and have noticed that most append the session ID or similar to the logout page as a get variable.

Why do they do this?

Is it not just safe/easier to just the destroy the session on logout.php and not pass in any ID?

Comment: Are you sure they're doing it only on logout? Most sites append sessid to the get request to insure that the user's session perpetuates in cases where they have disabled (or disallowed) cookies.

Comment: If it's not just the logout page but all the pages then it is a measure taken to mitigate cross-site script forgery risks. Learn more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of any reason why they would need to add a `get` param only when logging out.

Adding some token to an URL can be used to [prevent abuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) or when the session id is added to the url to also make session work when cookies are disbled on the client side.

**Update**

From the [linked article](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/08/security-review-creating-secure-php.html):

> However, a quick view of the file shows a fairly interesting issue. It requires the signature computed by logging in to be presented to the user to submit to the login page. **Presumably this was done as a form of CSRF protection**. **However, it also leaks the data necessary to take over a session to the user**. So we come to our 11th **vulnerability** so far:

**UPDATE2**

I've asked [ircmaxell in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3187855#3187855). And yup it is because of CSRF protection.

Comment: Example would be the one this guy is reviewing:- http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/08/security-review-creating-secure-php.html

Comment: @StephenAdrianRathbone he's idling in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php),so why don't you go directly to the source :)